Convert double variable to hour in R
I have a variable which represents hours (in R). The variable is double and an example of it is 1467. I want to convert the 1467 into 1467H 0M 0S. Thanks!
At first I tried this:
dataframe_2014 %>%
mutate(hours(hours_stay))
And I obtained what I wished. But then, I load the chron package and the result is not accurate by now, I obtained 0.
